# Warning: First parameter must either be an object or the name of an existing class in ............../plugins/xe-preview/xe-preview.php on line 24

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling, plugins

I installed a plugin on my WordPress website and I'm getting this error:

> **Warning:** First parameter must either be an object or the name of an existing class in **/home/customer/www/XXXXXXXXXXX/public_html/wp-content/plugins/xe-preview/xe-preview.php on line 24**

Unfortunately the plugin provider is really not able to solve the issue.

I used the WordPress plugin on different hosting, different PHP versions, different WordPress version also.

Maybe anybody has an idea?

`[xe-preview key="{API-Key}"]` = API Key is correct.

```php
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: XE Preview
Description: [xe-preview key="{API-Key}"]
*/
define( 'XEP_PLUGIN', __FILE__ );
define( 'XEP_PLUGIN_DIR', untrailingslashit( dirname( XEP_PLUGIN ) ) );
define( 'XEP_PLUGIN_VIEWS_DIR', XEP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/views/' );

function render($attributes){
    $key= 0;
    $out ="";
    if (isset($attributes["key"])){
        $key = $attributes["key"];
    }
    $url = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);
    $catid = 0;
    if(isset($_GET['catid'])) {
        $catid = $_GET['catid'];
    }
    $api_url = "https://xeev.app/en/tmpl_api_v3?key=$key&catid=$catid";
    $j_data = file_get_contents($api_url);
    $data = json_decode($j_data);
    if (property_exists($data,"data")){
        ob_start();
        include(XEP_PLUGIN_VIEWS_DIR."list.php");
        $out = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    }
    return $out;

}

add_action('init', 'init_page');
function init_page() {
    wp_register_style( 'xe_style', plugins_url('/css/style.css', __FILE__), false, '1.0.0', 'all');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_style');
function enqueue_style(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'xe_style' );
}
add_shortcode( 'xe-preview', 'render' );
```

Comment: From that code, [property_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) expects `$data` (the first parameter) to be an object (or a class name) and it seems that it's something else (but not an object nor a class name), hence the warning message. Try doing `var_dump( $data );` to see what its value is and update your code accordingly.

Comment: you mean, i shall change like this: .....if (var_dump($data,"data")) ?

Comment: No, that's just for troubleshooting. To check what is it you're getting from the API because `$data` isn't an object as the code expects it to be and that's why you're this warning message. Since it seem you're not that familiar with coding in general you might want to consider reaching out to the people who maintain your website/project (or to hire a freelance dev) and ask them to look into this for you.

Comment: thanks mate, in order to be sure i created a new clean wordpress website and installed only this plugin. I also contacted before some freelancers to try to solve this issue. But I highly believe there is an issue with the API of this plugin. I assume only the developer/platform can solve this. Its just my guess…i am also in contact with the plugin guys and lets see if they can find something or not

Comment: IMO the problem is with the plugin itself, it might not be handling the API responses the right way (eg. from one glance I can tell you it doesn't account for when the API is unreachable, or if it returns an error message, etc). The person who developed this plugin should be able to fix this issue, or anyone with some PHP skills for that matter.